# Angular 2 Mobile Toolkit --mobile flag doesn't work

Tags: angular, mobile

I'm trying to create a new mobile app via `Angular 2 Mobile Toolkit` (https://mobile.angular.io/).

When I type: `ng new hello-mobile --mobile`, I get this error:

```
`The option '--mobile' is not registered with the new command. 
Run 'ng new --help' for a list of supported options.
```

In `ng new --help` I don't see anything with `mobile`.

Here is my `ng -v` result:

```
@angular/cli: 1.0.2
node: 6.10.1
os: win32 x64
```

What I'm missing? This work only with some other angular version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The angular-cli --mobile flag was removed and a new solution is under design.

The readme in the mobile-kit repo is not correct in the description of the angular-cli generation while Angular-Cli doesn't support the --mobile flag.

See this Github Issues:

https://github.com/angular/mobile-toolkit/issues/138

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2228